# Setting Focus to WebBrowser Control in Visual Basic 2010 by Clicking a Button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

## The Program

I have a program that is similar to any web browser; however, I have a toolstrip with a text box and a button. I want to be able to use the Sendkeys.Send method to send the text within the textbox to the webbrowser control. The problem is that in order to click the button to send the text, the webbrowser must be focused before clicking the button. This is an issue because you can't type text into the textbox before sending the text, otherwise the webbrowser control will lose its focus and prevent it from sending anything.

## My Goal

After the webbrowser loads, and I navigate to a page, I want to be able to send text to it using a textbox and a button. So, in order to do this I must (assumingly) programmatically focus the webbrowser control.

### My Code:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem15_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Handles ToolStripMenuItem15.Click

    WebBrowser1.Focus() ' set focus to webbrowser (!DOES NOT WORK!)
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
    SendKeys.Send(ToolStripTextBox1.Text & " " & ToolStripTextBox4.Text)
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")

End Sub
```

I'm also aware of the "InvokeMember" method used to invoke specific elements within the webpage, but I don't need that because the textbox (within the loaded webpage) is already focused. I just need the webbrowser CONTROL to be focused in order to send the text using the button.

EDIT: If it helps to visual the program, it only contains a webbrowser, and a toolstrip with a textbox and button.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebBrowser1.Document.Focus()` instead of `WebBrowser1.Focus()`.